# Adwords API error: ReportDownloadError.INVALID_VERSION. c# client library

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get the .NET client library code samples to return a criteria performance report but can't get the code to function. I'm getting an error when clicking the "Download Criteria Report button" on the AdWords.Examples.CSharp.OAuth test page.

The error is as following:

> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399
>      Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Util.Reports.ReportUtilities.DownloadReport(String downloadUrl, String postBody) in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\src\AdWords\Util\Reports\New\ReportUtilities.cs:183
>
> [AdWordsReportsException: AdWordsReportsException: One or more AdWords Report download errors have occurred.
>
> ReportDownloadError.INVALID_VERSION. (Error: ReportDownloadError.INVALID_VERSION, FieldPath: , Trigger: )]
>
> Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Util.Reports.ReportUtilities.DownloadReport(String downloadUrl, String postBody) in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\src\AdWords\Util\Reports\New\ReportUtilities.cs:204
>      Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Util.Reports.ReportUtilities.GetReport() in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\src\AdWords\Util\Reports\New\ReportUtilities.cs:166
>      Google.Api.Ads.Common.Util.Reports.AdsReportUtilities.GetResponse() in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\src\Common\Util\Reports\AdsReportUtilities.cs:162
>      Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Util.Reports.ReportUtilities.GetResponse() in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\src\AdWords\Util\Reports\New\ReportUtilities.cs:310
>      Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Examples.CSharp.OAuth.Default.OnDownloadReportButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\examples\AdWords\csharp\oauth\Default.aspx.cs:100
>
> [ApplicationException: Failed to download report.]
>      Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Examples.CSharp.OAuth.Default.OnDownloadReportButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in C:\Development\Projects\google.adwords.api\examples\AdWords\csharp\oauth\Default.aspx.cs:104
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9712662
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35 
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639

What am i missing or doing wrong?

My main goal is to retrieve an XML feed that i can display on a webpage.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version are you using?
if you are using old version, update them.

Here is Deprecation Schedule.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/sunset-dates